# Body biasing of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

Why does body biasing (i.e when \$V_{bs}\$ is less than 0 V) leads to increase in threshold voltage? I am looking for an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative bias on the body of an N-channel MOS transistor increases the width of the depletion regions around the source and drain terminals. This makes it more difficult for the gate to establish the E-field gradient required to create the population inversion of charge carriers near the surface of the semiconductor that becomes the active channel of the transistor.

Comment: The system that you should be explaining is the gate to channel to body (AKA back gate).  the S/D 's are really just contacts to the channel and while the S/D depletion regions DO effect the transistor (i.e. DIBL, GIDL pinch-off etc.) the effect here is solely about the effect of the back gate on the channel.